# Recorrer los datos de un checkbox seleccionado con asp

Tags: sql-server, asp

Tengo una tabla que me entrega datos a partir de un query, donde me entrega el `id, nombre, enviar`.

Al seleccionar el enviar y presionar el botón **guardar**, esto realiza una nueva acción.

```
    <form name="formulario" method="post" action="informacion.asp" onsubmit="return validacion(this)"><table class="table table-bordered  table-striped table_filter">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                  <th>ID</th>
                                  <th>NOMBRE</th>
                                  <th>ENVIAR</th>
                                </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
    <!--#include file="cadenaconexion.asp"-->
    <%
        Strconn = CadenaConexion
        Set Conn = Server.Createobject("adodb.connection")
        Conn.open StrConn

        sSQL="select * from datos where valor=1"
        Set rs = Conn.Execute(sSQL)
        While (Not rs.EOF)

    %>
                                <tr>
                                  <td><%=(rs("ID"))%>
                                  <td><%=(rs("NOMBRE"))%></td>
                                  <td><input name="info_enviar" id="info_enviar" type="checkbox"  value="<%=(rs("ID"))%>"></td>
                                  </tr>
    <%
            rs.MoveNext
            Wend
    %>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
<%
            If Request.Servervariables("REQUEST_METHOD") = "POST" Then

                For Each dato In (Request.Form("info_enviar"))
                   solicitud = dato & ","
                    Response.Write (dato & "<br>" )
                Next

sSQL="select * from datos where id=" & dato
Set rs = Conn.Execute(sSQL)
                While (Not rs.EOF)
ID = rs("ID")
email= CadenaEmail & rs("EMAIL") & ","
rs.MoveNext
                Wend
Mensaje = "HOLA, esto es una prueba"
EnviarMail email, Mensaje
%>
</form
```

Hasta aquí me entrega la respuesta del query solicitado, pero una vez que selecciono los checkbox, que pueden ser todos o pueden ser algunos los seleccionados, tengo el problema de no se como rescatar los checkbox seleccionados y que me envíe un mail SOLO a los seleccionados.

Hoy en día me funciona el mail, pero enviándolo a todo el resultado que me entrega el SQL, estoy clara que no se como separar el código para que me envíe el mail a los check seleccionados.

Answer (score 0):

He cambiado el codigo y me a funcionado, si alguien me pudiese corroborar si esta bien implementado lo que acabo de hacer lo agradeería

```
<%
            If Request.Servervariables("REQUEST_METHOD") = "POST" Then
enviar = request.Form("info_enviar")
If Trim(enviar) <> "" Then
    id = split(enviar,",")
    for i = 0 to UBound(id)
        sSQL="select * from datos where id=" & id(i)
Set rs = Conn.Execute(sSQL)
                While (Not rs.EOF)
ID = rs("ID")
email= CadenaEmail & rs("EMAIL") & ","
rs.MoveNext
                Wend
Mensaje = "HOLA, esto es una prueba"
EnviarMail email, Mensaje
    Next

%>
```